# PHP MySQL SELECT statement return null

Tags: php, mysql, null

I want to select data from `MySQL` with a a where condition.

I'm sure the condition is false that's why it shouldn't return any data or any row but it returns null. I checked it with  `$stmt2->num_rows > 0` and this condition is true.

**How can i prevent this from happening?**

*How my code suppose to work* : this condition should be false for the first time and be true after I insert some data.

I think it's for `SUM()` that is used in select statement. **How can I do that?**

```
$q2="SELECT SUM(liked), SUM(disliked) FROM like_dislike WHERE post_id=?";
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare($q2);
$stmt2->bind_param('i', $post_id);
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->store_result();
$stmt2->bind_result($like_status, $dislike_status);
if ($stmt2->num_rows > 0 ) {
    $stmt2->fetch();
}
else {
    $like_status =0;
    $dislike_status =0;
}
```

**My select statement result in phpmyadmin**:

[image: select statement null]

Comment: come again? the `post_id` is 34 and there is no such thing as `post_id=34` in that table(i mean there is no record)

Comment: i attached a screenshot from select result

Comment: Please show your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) :

> SUM([DISTINCT] expr)
>
> Returns the sum of expr. If the return set has no rows, SUM() returns NULL. The DISTINCT keyword can be used to sum only the distinct values of expr.
>
> If there are no matching rows, SUM() returns NULL.

So you will always have NULL as result if you have no data.